# Extract a substring from a string in C#

Tags: c#, substring

How can I extract the substring "John Woo" from the below string in C#

CN=John Woo,OU=IT,OU=HO,DC=ABC,DC=com

Thanks !

Comment: tried to type something like "c# dn parsing" in some search engine ? http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9788/An-RFC-2253-Compliant-Distinguished-Name-Parser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can firstly split the string by the commas to get an array of strings, each of which is a name/value pair separated by `=`:

```
string input = "CN=John Woo,OU=IT,OU=HO,DC=ABC,DC=com";
var nameValuePairs = input.Split(new[] {','});
```

Then you can split the first name/value pair like so:

```
var nameValuePair = nameValuePairs[0].Split(new[]{'='});
```

Finally, the value part will be `nameValuePair[1]`:

```
var value = nameValuePair[1];
```

(No error handling shown above - you would of course have to add some.)

Answer (score 5):

You could use a [`Lookup<TKey, TElement>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460184.aspx):

```
string text = "CN=John Woo,OU=IT,OU=HO,DC=ABC,DC=com";
var keyValues = text.Split(',')
    .Select(s => s.Split('='))
    .ToLookup(kv => kv[0], kv => kv.Last());
string cn = keyValues["CN"].FirstOrDefault();  // John Woo
// or, if multiple values with the same key are allowed (as suggested in the given string)
string dc = string.Join(",", keyValues["DC"]); // ABC,com
```

Note that you neither get an exception if the key is not present(as in a dictionary) nor if the key is not uniqe (as in a dictionary). The value is a `IEnumerable<TElement>`.

Comment: string cn = keyValues["CN"].FirstOrDefault();  returns null ? but I can see the values when debugging?

Comment: Where you can see values? Maybe you see values in the lookup but theres none with `"CN"` as key. Note that it's case-sensitive(you can change if desired).

Comment: var keyValues = line.Split(',').Select(s => s.Split('=')).ToLookup(kv => kv[0].Trim(), kv => kv.Last().Trim()); -- Make sure to trim the key and value :)

Comment: @OliverCiappara: Yes, a good idea if you don't care about empty spaces

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
var regex = new Regex("CN=(?<mygroup>.*?),");
var match = regex.Match("CN=John Woo,OU=IT,OU=HO,DC=ABC,DC=com");
if(match.Success)
{
    string result = match.Groups["mygroup"].Value;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this (this is a non generic answer) :

```
var name = str.Split(',').Where(n => n.StartsWith("CN=")).FirstOrDefault().Substring(3);
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this

```
var s = "CN=John Woo,OU=IT,OU=HO,DC=ABC,DC=com";
// this give you a enumarable of anonymous key/value
var v = s.Split(',') 
         .Select(x => x.Split('='))
         .Select(x => new
                      {
                          key = x[0],
                          value = x[1],
                      });
var name = v.First().value; // John Woo
```

Answer (score 0):

I created the below code of my own and finally got the substring I needed. The below code works for every substring that I want to extract that falls after "CN=" and before first occurrence of ",".

```
string name = "CN=John Woo,OU=IT,OU=HO,DC=ABC,DC=com";
int index1 = name.IndexOf("=") + 1;
int index2 = name.IndexOf(",") - 3;
string managerName = name.Substring(index1, index2);
```

The Result was "John Woo"

Thanks all for your help...